# how to covert Sql Query to linq

Tags: linq

Anyone Please Help to convert the following SQL Query to Linq

```
select 
  PersonRank,
  amount,
  (Select sum(p2.Amount) from @PersonRank p2 where p2.PersonRank <= p1.PersonRank) 
from @PersonRank P1 
order by PersonRank
```

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var result = db.PersonRank(i => new
                        {
                            PersonRank = i.PersonRank,
                            amount = i.amount,
                            PersonRankSum = (db.PersonRank
                                              .Where(t => t.PersonRank <= i.PersonRank)
                                              .Sum(t => t.Amount)
                                             )

                        }).OrderBy(i => i.PersonRank);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = 
    from pr in context.PersonRanks
    orderby pr.PersonRank
    select new 
        { 
            pr.PersonRank, 
            pr.Amount, 
            Sum = context.PersonRanks.Where(p => p.PersonRank <= pr.PersonRank).Sum(p => p.Amount)
        };
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.